# What's the correct choice for this question with "may ..." sentense?

Tags: grammar

[image]

I know "may have broken" could be a correct choice but it is not an option, so I was going for the option a) since it's grammatically correct(?)

Could someone tell me what's the correct answer here, and why are other options incorrect? I'm generally confused by the "may ..." formed structure.

Comment: It's a stupid test. b and d are ungrammatical, but a (possible *future* break) and c (possible *past* break) are both syntactically fine. Note that *It **is** broken* and *It **has** broken* are in most contexts equivalent and interchangeable.